# Adding TabControl to Form with Exisiting Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, tabcontrol

In WinForms C# using .Net 2.0 I want to add a TabControl to a Form that has existing controls. Is there a way to move all the controls into a tab control without Visual Studio blowing away all my event handlers the like? Using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, make the form as large as possible and draw a tab control on the right side of the form. Then select all the controls on the left side and drag them on the tab control. Now your event handlers will remain intact and controls will be placed on the tab control nicely.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that :) Thanks so much for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would select all of the controls on your form, hit Ctrl-X (cut them), put the TabControl on your form and make it as big as you need, then hit Ctrl-V to paste all of the controls into the TabControl.  This will maintain the state of all of your controls..you won't lose event handlers or anything.

Comment: That was the method that I tried at first. It broke all the connections and totally destroyed the form I was working in. I didn't lose my code but I lost all the links to my code. Nothing worked after I pasted it back in.

Comment: I thought it would work to. That's why I posted question. I flail for about an hour doing it the hard way before stopping and asking about the easy way :)